# A* 3 robots touch each other

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence, distance, robot, heuristics

It is all about 3 robots, named A, B, and C, that can move around their environment using informed search. The environment contains obstacles. **The 3 robots need to meet at some point such that the total distance they walk is minimum.**

To make the problem a little computationally simpler, we will limit the obstacles to be rectangles. The 3 robots are always circles with radius 1. The goal state is to have the 3 robots (circles) to touch each other; the distance between the centers of every two robots is 1 unit. While moving, robots must not cut across any of the obstacles. In every step, one of the 3 robots moves one unit from the current location in each of the four directions: left, right, up and down. A move from one point to another must not go through any obstacle.

***I just need a good heuristic function that can approximate the distance between the 3 robots can you help me guys?***

I solved this issue here is the code [Github code](https://github.com/ata333/My-Projects/blob/master/Moving_Robots_Problem.java)

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: You should just check general pathfinding algorithm that best matches your situation. The simplest way is probably to use standard A* -algorithm and find the smallest travel cost from each robot to each other first, and then move accordingly. In general (for pathfinding) it matters not what is the shape of the objects or environment, as you describe possible paths as lines connecting nodes.  Avoiding obstacles is a whole another problem which needs obstacle avoidance algorithms, basically drawing lines to every single node and checking if it crosses an obstacle. If yes, that node is not usable

Comment: @StackingForHeap You're correct i did 90% of what you said

Answer (score 0):

I assume here that you want to minimize the number of total steps (only one robot moves at a time). If the robots all move at the same time and you want to minimize the time needed the solution would be different. Also, some fine tuning is necessary becuase the robots should just touch, not come to the same point.

You actually need a lower bound, not an approximation. A good lower bound can be calculated by disregarding any obstacles and check how many moves are necessary on an empty field. Since the robots can only move horizontally or vertically we consider these directions separately.

Take the horizontal direction first. The leftmost and the rightmost robot need to meet somewhere between them so independent where they meet, in total they have to move the horizontal distance between them. If they meet at the horizontal position of the middle robot, the middle does not have to move. So the horizontal steps necessary in any case is the horizontal distance between the leftmost and rightmost robot. Call this the horizontal span.

A similar argument holds for the vertical direction.

In total a lower bound is therefore the vertical span plus the horizontal span.

Answer (score 0):

If each robot moves at the same time and it is known where the obstacles are at the beginning(so a known map), and obstacles are none moving this would work. Uou would need to generate a grid of sorts using a wavefront algorithm. This would be done for each robot in the beginning. Then going through each grid add the steps from each robot. Then find the grid with the lowest amount.